# Increase the visibility of the association bonus by documenting it with the other privileges

Tags: feature-request, privileges, association-bonus

Currently, the first time a user on the Stack Exchange network reaches 200 reputation, they get an extra 100 rep on that account and all their [associated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/association) accounts.

**I believe this should be documented as a privilege at 200 rep** (along with the lessening of adverts).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you want to change the process. How would it work differently if it were a privilege than it works now?

Comment: You seem to be requesting this feature to improve user awareness of the other SE sites. Do you think it would be more efficient than the list of sites already available in the page footer and in the MultiCollider SuperDropdown™?

Comment: @Dan, so the privilege notification message would list [the 106 sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) along with their descriptions? It may be a little too long to be useable, let alone read in the first place.

Comment: How about adding that information to the [reduced ads](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) privilege page?

Comment: Well, most privileges give you more than what they are named after - so, in this respect it will not be different, though I see merit to your suggestion. Point being that on that page the information will certainly gain more visibility than currently.

Comment: +1, I love this idea. [Some concept art](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fHWkj.png)

Comment: "Verified" would be a bit misleading though - Twitter and others use it to point out members whose identity has been verified offline. "Established" would be more fitting

Comment: I've edited the question to try to reflect this comment thread. I've removed the reference to "verified user", as that seems to have caused more confusion than enlightenment.

Comment: "I believe this should be documented as a privilege at 200 rep (along with the lessening of adverts)". This part is a no-brainer. It still hasn't happened 11 months later. Please add the association bonus to [/help/privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges)